# A dialog that must be finished before anything else takes place

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, dialog, modal-dialog

Is there a simple way in Java to create a dialog that will not let you change focus from it until it has been closed? Such as the windows dialogs that gray out the entire screen and only let you interact with it until you satisfy it.

Comment: See [How to Use Modality in Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html)..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily do this using a JDialog

```
JDialog dialog = new JDialog(Frame owner, "My modal dialog", **true**)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make your dialog modal which blocks user input. From [Oracle modality tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html):

> Modal dialog box — A dialog box that blocks input to some other
>   top-level windows in the application, except for windows created with
>   the dialog box as their owner. The modal dialog box captures the
>   window focus until it is closed, usually in response to a button
>   press.

There are four types of Modality (again from tutorial):

> - Modeless type — A modeless dialog box does not block any other window    while it is visible.
> - Document-modal type — A document-modal dialog box blocks all windows    from the same document, except windows from its child
>     hierarchy. In    this context, a document is a hierarchy of windows
>     that share a    common ancestor, called the document root, which is
>     the closest    ancestor window without an owner.
> - Application-modal type — An application-modal dialog box blocks all    windows from the same application, except windows from its child
>     hierarchy. If several applets are launched in a browser environment,
>     the browser is allowed to treat them either as separate applications
>     or as a single application. This behavior is
>     implementation-dependent.
> - Toolkit-modal type — A toolkit-modal dialog box blocks all windows    that run in the same toolkit, except windows from its child
>     hierarchy. If several applets are launched, all of them run with the
>     same toolkit. Hence, a toolkit-modal dialog box shown from an applet
>     may affect other applets and all windows of the browser instance that 
>     embeds the Java runtime environment for this toolkit.

You can use [JDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html) to create your dialog. Just use one of the constructors that takes the modal flag and set modal to true. If you want you can specify one of the types above, but by default it will be `APPLICATION_MODAL`.

This is a simple constructor you can use:

```
public JDialog(Dialog owner, String title, boolean modal)
```

So you just add

```
JDialog dialog = new JDialog(owner, "My test modal dialog", true);
```